# Installing idle3 on kali 2020.2

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle, kali-linux

I successfully installed python 3.8.3 on kali linux. However, i am unable to install idle3. I tried several methods suggested but none work. One of the methods I used was "sudo apt-get install idle3 " the error message it gives me is "E: Unable to locate package idle3". How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

IDLE uses tkinter and is typically installed only when tkinter is.  On linux, the separate package is usually `python-tk` and at least one site claims that this is so on kali.  (I searched `kali linux python tkinter`.) So try the following and if it does not work, look more on the kali-linux site.

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I had to add a '3' to get it to work.
2. sudo apt-get install python3-tk
3. Then saw this answer:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357060/e-unable-to-locate-package-idle3-in-ubuntu-18-04
4. Don't forget to run sudo apt-get update
5. Have to install the right version of Idle to match your version of Python. Check your version by typing python3 into cli.
6. sudo apt install idle-python3.11 (mine is 3.11.2, just typed in 3.11 to get it to work, yours may be a different version).
7. Probably need to run sudo apt-get update again.
8. Ta-da, now Idle is showing up in my applications. What a ridiculous pita linux is. :D